# First-order logics expressively equivalent to the computable languages

Tags: model-theory, computability-theory, automata-theory

There is a really nice theorem that the subsets of $(\Sigma^*, =_{el}, \preceq, (S_a)_{a \in \Sigma})$ definable in first-order logic are exactly the regular sets.

Where:

- $\Sigma^*$ is the set of finite words on finite alphabet $\Sigma$
- $x =_{el} y$ if $x$ and $y$ are equal length
- $x \preceq y$ if $x$ is a prefix of $y$
- $S_a(x)$ is $x$ concatenated with the letter $a$, for $a \in \Sigma$

I imagine there being similar equivalences of the form:
The subsets of $\Sigma^*$ which are definable by a particular type of first-order logical formula over a particular language are exactly the computable sets.

Does anyone know of any nice such equivalences?

Comment: Are you sure this is quite correct?  You should only be able to obtain star free languages this way  I think. For all regular languages you should need second order monadic logic.  Your predicates are not the standard ones for Buchi's theorem but I believe it defines the same languages. There is a whole subfield of computer science that talks about logical descriptions of language classes.

Comment: You might look at the book https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-03182-7

Comment: Actually, there's a pretty big **obstacle** to this happening. The most common way for a structure $\mathcal{A}$ with domain $\mathbb{N}$ in a computable language $\Sigma$ to have all definable sets be computable is for $\mathcal{A}$ to be **decidable**, that is, for the full elementary diagram of $\mathcal{A}$ to be computable. *(Note that models of complete decidable theories need not be decidable in this strong sense!)* However, if $\mathcal{A}$ is decidable in this sense then the $\mathcal{A}$-definable sets fall well short of the class of computable sets since we can directly diagonalize.

Comment: This is correct! The result is documented in "Decision Problems for Multiple Successor Arithmetics" by J.W. Thatcher. You can implement a finite state automaton by having a separate word $x_q$ for each state, and require that the nth character of $x_q$ is a marker character $a$ iff the automaton is in state $q$ just before reading the nth character of the input. The equal length predicate lets you line everything up even without being able to use variables for natural numbers.